# How do I add a second plot behind the first one in matplotlib.pyplot? It's either on top or invisible

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make a bar graph showing current measurements compared to a one-month moving average, by placing blue bars for current data ('a') on top of slightly wider grey bars for the one-month average ('b').

Here is the simplest version of my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [4, 5, 6],
                    'b': [3,4,5]})
x=np.arange(len(data['a']))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x,data['a'])
rt_ax = ax.twinx()
rt_ax.bar(x,data['b'],width=0.9,color='grey')
rt_ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
# ax.set_zorder(rt_ax.get_zorder()+1)

plt.show()
```

That creates the bars I want, but the grey bars are on top:

[image: Plot with fat grey bars on top of blue bars]

If I uncomment the ax.set_zorder line, I see the blue bars, but the grey bars disappear:

[image: Plot with blue bars and no grey bars]

Comment: The best thing to do, is to leave out the `twinx` and plot everything on the same ax. The bars will be shown in the order they are drawn, so draw the grey bars first.  If you really need `twinx`, you could change the plot background from white to transparent via `ax.set_facecolor('none')`.

Comment: Thanks, `ax.set_facecolor('none')` did the trick! (I need to use the secondary axis because in my application, I have count on the left y-axis and proportion on the right y-axis, and then the comparison data is plotted relative to the proportion axis.)

Comment: Can I get a secondary y-axis without using `twinx`? I need to make graphs that look like this: [graph example](https://i.redd.it/w4d8802fkbj41.png)

Comment: `twinx` is indeed the correct choice when the y-axes are different. Note that with `twinx` everything that is on one ax is drawn completely before anything on the other ax. Every ax is as a complete layer. Inside that layer, everything is drawn again in sublayers, such as bars first, then lines, then text on top. `zorder` of an ax can change the order between axes. `zorder` for individual components can change the order in which the components of an ax are drawn.

Answer (score 0):

> Add alpha

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [4, 5, 6],
                    'b': [3,4,5]})
x=np.arange(len(data['a']))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(x,data['a'])
rt_ax = ax.twinx()
rt_ax.bar(x,data['b'],width=0.9,color='grey', alpha=0.6)
rt_ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())

plt.show()
```

[image]